# How to show equivalence of two definitions of a limit point

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

In an inner product space $R$, one definition of a limit point of a set $N \Subset R$ is that it is the point $f$ in $R$ which is a limit of a sequence from $N$ (in other words , there is a sequence $f1,f2,...$ of points in N, such that the sequence $||f1-f||, ||f2-f||, ...$ converges to $0$).

But another definition is : $f$ is a limit point of $N$ if for each $\epsilon>0$, there is an $f'$ of $N$ with $||f'-f||<\epsilon$.

How can it be shown that the first definition follows from the second?

Answer (score 1):

Pick $\epsilon = 1$, then $\epsilon = 1/2$, then $\epsilon = 1/3$, ....